# Moment.js と getTimer を使用してconsole.log()で現在時間を表示すると日本時間ではない

Tags: javascript, monaca

下記のように入力して、結果を見ると日本時間ではないようです。
これはなぜでしょうか？

```
var now = new Date().getTime(),
_1_min_from_now = new Date(now + 1*1000);
console.log(_1_min_from_now); //"2017-10-16T04:54:29.935Z"
var now2 = moment().calendar();
console.log(now2)             //Today at 1:54 PM
var oneminfromnow = moment().add(1, 'munites')
console.log(oneminfromnow)    //"2017-10-16T04:54:28.941Z"
```

monacaのサーバーのある場所のタイムゾーンが出ているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クライアントのローカル時間がUTC(協定世界時)で表示されていると考えられます。
ローカルが日本時間と想定されるので、`2017-10-16T04:54:29`などの時間をプラス9時間すれば期待していた時間と合うのではないでしょうか。

`"2017-10-16T04:54:29.935Z"`の時間表記は、`"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ"`(TとZはそのまま)という意味は分かると思いますが、これは[ISO 8601のタイムゾーン指定子](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#.E3.82.BF.E3.82.A4.E3.83.A0.E3.82.BE.E3.83.BC.E3.83.B3.E6.8C.87.E5.AE.9A.E5.AD.90)が付いたフォーマットです。

`Z`で終わっていればUTC、`+0900`で終わっていればUTC+9時間で日本時間と同じになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！ご指摘の通りでした。moment.jsの公式ページでも確認し、フォーマットを指定すればUTCではなく、Local Timeで表示されるようです。素早い回答をいただけてとても助かりました。